# How come my %d function won't work?

Tags: python-2.7

Here is my code, and the problem I am having trouble with the %d in the while loop, when i run the program, it doesn't print a number it actually just prints the line along with %d. What am I doing wrong here?

```
smallest = 1
largest = 100

answer = int(raw_input("Think of a number between 1 and 100"))
correct  = 68
while (correct != 'yes'):
    guess = (smallest+largest)/2
    print guess
    correct = raw_input("Is your answer equal to %d"  + "? If not, then please press enter 's' if it's smaller or 'l' if larger.")%d(guess, )
    if (correct=='l'):
        smallest = guess + 1
    elif (correct=='s'):
        largest = guess - 1
else:
    print ("Hurray, I got it!!")
    Cancel_FC = raw_input("Press any key to close console")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this set:

```
correct = raw_input("Is your answer equal to %d"  + "? If not, then please press enter 's' if it's smaller or 'l' if larger.")%d(guess, )
```

Try this instead:

```
correct = raw_input(("Is your answer equal to %d"  + "? If not, then please press enter 's' if it's smaller or 'l' if larger.") % (guess))
```

The change is from your formatting of `)%d(guess, )` to `) % (guess)`

Comment: I think I tried that earleir without the comma and it still wouldn't work, I will try again. Will report back with results.

Comment: Yeah, it's still giving me the %d >.>

Comment: While single non-tuples used in string interpolation don't need to be put into a tuple, having them in a tuple is not a bug.

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

```
correct = raw_input( ("Is your answer equal to %d"  + "? If not, then please press enter 's' if it's smaller or 'l' if larger.") % (guess) )
```

Note the additional parenthesis.

Comment: Arghh, darn you brackets!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! -_-"I feel so bad now for overlooking this mistake. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is:

```
correct = raw_input("Is your answer equal to %d? If not, then please press enter 's' if it's smaller or 'l' if larger."%(guess))
```

First, the formatting operator is just `%`, not `%d` -- the latter is what you put inside the format string. Second, the operator has to be after the format string, not outside the argument list of `raw_input`; it operates on the string to its left and the list to its right.

You don't need the comma inside `(guess)`, but it works either way.